# NodeJS for Slackware

Tags: software-installation, slackware, node.js, npm

I want to run NodeJS on Slackware based distro named [PuppyLinux](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Puppy53). Since I am used to Ubuntu and CentOS (the simple Linux land), I found it pretty hard to find a NodeJS package to run on Slackware.

I tried building it from source, but it took loooong time to install `gcc` and dependencies and then I found some silly compilation errors (can't find errno.h!)

Are there any NodeJS (and npm) binaries to run on Slackware? Any one succeeded to build it?

Comment: All the basic dependencies like gcc and glibc come as defaults in regular Slackware. Perhaps you'd have an easier time building the package on a Slackware install and then copying the resulting binary over to your PuppyLinux system.

Comment: Also, did you install glibc? Not being able to find errno.h suggests that perhaps you haven't installed it. What do you get if you run `# locate -u` and then `# locate errno.h`?

Comment: Use the  slackbuild way http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/network/node/

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger thanks for the tip. I found that this distro is **very** trimmed. A lot of packages are removed. It was missing glibc, binutils and kernel-headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, I've got install that package on Slackware Linux using the slackbuild way. Here's the link:

```
http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/development/nodejs/
```

Comment: I built exactly that, but it doesn't come with `npm`.

Comment: Hi @Geremia, Firstly, You must be sure, the npm directory was created after the installation (i.e. `ls /usr/lib/node_modules/`). If it exists, it should contain a `bin` directory, and just add a symbolic link to it: `ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm`. Once that process was completed, you can use the npm command, i.e. `npm install <pkg_name>`. Note: to create the symbolic link you need to be root.

Comment: [Audrius Kažukauskas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870151/audrius-ka%C5%BEukauskas), who maintained that SlackBuild, said it's outdated; it's version 0.10.33! He says to use http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/development/nodejs/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I just built this slackbuild https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/development/nodejs/ yesterday (2016-11-10) and can confirm that it installs `npm` at `/usr/bin/npm`.

```
$ ls -al `which npm`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Nov 10 20:24 /usr/bin/npm -> ../lib64/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js*
```